# Is there anyway to perform this animation on HTML5, CSS3, and Jquery?

Tags: html, css, slider, jquery-animate, fadeout

So basically what I am trying to achieve is,

- when people click on first image, the rest will slide and fade, then the content loads up,
- when people close, it will be back into 4 images,
- when people click on 2nd image; images 1, 3 and 4 will slide and fade out, content shows up and so on.

I tried to play around with Jquery, and still ended up with zero result.

Here is the link:
http://homethai.com.au/testing/test.swf

Comment: It's definietly achieveable, but I don't know exactly how anyone would go about it. In any case i think that's a really cool photo animation idea. sorry for those of you who think that's a useless comment..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This (with a bit of trial and error) is actually possible mostly through CSS, with plain JavaScript used only to toggle the class names (when a block is clicked and when a close link is clicked).

If `.block.active` in the CSS is replaced with `.block:hover` so that each block will expand on hover, and the close links (and styles) are removed, then no JS is required at all.

- [Demo](http://shaquin.tk/experiments/anim1.html)
- [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MyqFR/1/)
- [Fiddle without displaying code, much less cramped](http://jsfiddle.net/MyqFR/1/show/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="closelink">X</div>
</div>
<div class="block">
    <div class="closelink">X</div>
</div>
<div class="block">
    <div class="closelink">X</div>
</div>
<div class="block">
    <div class="closelink">X</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    text-align: center
}
.block {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background: #08f;
    margin: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    transition: margin 1s;
    -moz-transition: margin 1s;
    -webkit-transition: margin 1s;
    -o-transition: margin 1s;
    -ms-transition: margin 1s;
    user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none
}
.block .closelink {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    right: -20px;
    top: -20px;
    visibility: hidden;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Segoe UI, Tahoma, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    background: #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px
}
.block.active {
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-right: 200px
}
.block.active .closelink {
    visibility: visible
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
window.addEventListener('load', init, false);
function init() {
    var blocks = document.getElementsByClassName('block');
    var closeLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('closelink');
    for(i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
        blocks[i].addEventListener('click', blockClicked, false);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < closeLinks.length; i++) {
        closeLinks[i].addEventListener('click', closeLinkClicked, false);
    }
}
function blockClicked(e) {
    var blocks = document.getElementsByClassName('block');
    for(i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
        blocks[i].className = 'block';
    }
    e.target.className = 'block active';
}
function closeLinkClicked(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.target.parentElement.className = 'block';
}
```

Comment: thanks alot buddy, with the script provided, i finally manage to modify it and let it work perfectly. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course.

The set up is:

1. Absolutely position each element in the right place.
2. Make a class called `.leftOffscreen` which sets left to -100px, and `.rightOffscreen` which sets it to whatever max you want. (Once it's working, use transforms where you can instead of left/right because it will be hardware accelerated on some browsers and hence more performant)
3. Add CSS transitions to each image.

Algorithm:

1. On click, find which image you are by using [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/).
2. Loop through the images using [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/). If their index is less than the clicked one, add the class `leftOffscreen`, if they are more than, add `rightOffscreen`.
3. When the x is clicked, remove those classes from all images.